# What is this formal (perhaps old-fashioned) actual-state-of-affairs use of 'should' called?

Tags: modal-verbs, should

Here are three examples of the kind of thing I have in mind:

- “That he should do such a thing is terrible!”
- “That this should be the case is regrettable.”
- “That such a thing should happen is a blot on justice.”

In these examples, the ‘should’ is clearly not playing a commendatory role. Nor is it referring to purely hypothetical states of affairs, as in a conditional sentence (e.g., “Should such a thing occur, it would be terrible”). Instead, the ‘should’ is used in a construction that introduces an *actual* state of affairs, which in these examples is then negatively evaluated. (Of course, one could do the same thing with a positive evaluation—e.g., “That he should do such a thing is wonderful!”—but then you might mistakenly think the ‘should’ is commendatory.)

Does anyone know how grammarians or usage experts refer to this use of ‘should’? Ideally, I’d like a term I could plug into Google for further research. Thanks!

Comment: That he should do such a thing is terrible! = It is terrible that one should do such a thing = It is terrible for one to do such a thing. In the first example should is part of noun phrase, in second and third, noun phrase with should occurs as complements.

Comment: @RamPillai So is your answer that this use of 'should' is known as the "part of noun phrase" use of 'should'? I googled it, and I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: not really; 'should' is modal auxiliary that (here) is a constituent of noun phrase.

Comment: @RamPillai So are you saying that you're not sure what this particular use of 'should' is called?

Comment: The fourth definition of _should_ given by Oxford Dictionaries is "used in a clause with ‘that’ after a main clause describing feelings". (In your examples, the expression of feelings comes after the _should_ clause.) As far as I know, there is no official name for this usage.

Comment: My comment may be read modified as 'noun clause' not noun phrase.

Comment: @Michael2: Your questions sound like proving me wrong or not knowing ;) That's fine. However, Kate Bunting has given a better answer that I agree to.